# Is Stewart's "Early Transcendental's" equivalent to Calculus 1, 2, and 3?

Tags: book-recommendation

Is Stewart's "Early Transcendentals" equivalent to Calculus 1, 2, and 3? It seems to cover topics in most standard university calculus courses (1, 2, and 3), and I was wondering if it covered them in their entirety.

In other words, if I complete this book, would I be able to do well in most university Calculus 1/2/3 courses?

Comment: It is a book of good quality, for what it attempts to do. If you complete it, you will have very good computational experience. A proof-oriented course may still come as somewhat of a shock. A run of the mill university calculus "service" course will have nothing new.

Comment: I've read this ebook before and it's great for additional practice, but if you're looking for Calculus IV material, this isn't the right book. My university uses University Calculus Alternate Edition (Custom Edition if it's a binder version) for Calculus I-IV, so that great on a student's budget. This isn't a great book if you're in a proof heavy course.

Comment: Would you suggest a proof-based book to supplement it then?

Comment: Probably I would not suggest a proof-based book. Spivak is excellent. But learn some Physics instead.